# SMOTE for multilabel classification

Tags: multilabel-classification, smote

I have a dataset with almost 100 features and 6 target variables. I was able to identify that the target variables are highly unbalanced.

I tried using SMOTE to handle the unbalanced variables but it says imblearn's SMOTE does not support multi-label data. Is there an alternative to SMOTE that I can use for multilabel classification?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and came across [this medium article](https://medium.com/thecyphy/handling-data-imbalance-in-multi-label-classification-mlsmote-531155416b87) while looking for a solution. Might be helpful, and they provide their code for their MLSMOTE implementation.

Below is a code excerpt of their [MLSMOTE function](https://github.com/niteshsukhwani/MLSMOTE/blob/master/mlsmote.py):

```
def MLSMOTE(X,y, n_sample):
    """
    Give the augmented data using MLSMOTE algorithm
    
    args
    X: pandas.DataFrame, input vector DataFrame
    y: pandas.DataFrame, feature vector dataframe
    n_sample: int, number of newly generated sample
    
    return
    new_X: pandas.DataFrame, augmented feature vector data
    target: pandas.DataFrame, augmented target vector data
    """
    indices2 = nearest_neighbour(X)
    n = len(indices2)
    new_X = np.zeros((n_sample, X.shape[1]))
    target = np.zeros((n_sample, y.shape[1]))
    for i in range(n_sample):
        reference = random.randint(0,n-1)
        neighbour = random.choice(indices2[reference,1:])
        all_point = indices2[reference]
        nn_df = y[y.index.isin(all_point)]
        ser = nn_df.sum(axis = 0, skipna = True)
        target[i] = np.array([1 if val>2 else 0 for val in ser])
        ratio = random.random()
        gap = X.loc[reference,:] - X.loc[neighbour,:]
        new_X[i] = np.array(X.loc[reference,:] + ratio * gap)
    new_X = pd.DataFrame(new_X, columns=X.columns)
    target = pd.DataFrame(target, columns=y.columns)
    new_X = pd.concat([X, new_X], axis=0)
    target = pd.concat([y, target], axis=0)
    return new_X, target
```

They're finding the 5 nearest neighbors (NN) for each point in the minority class. The actual data generation process from what I understand is:

1. Choose one of the minority points at random.
2. Choose one of its 4 NN (excluding the point itself) at random.
3. Assign to `nn_df` a subset of the target df containing the 5 NN of the random point from *step 1*.
4. Sum the columns of `nn_df` and check if each sum is > 2, using `1 and 0` to represent `True` and `False`, respectively.

**The resultant vector is our oversampled y.**

5. Calculate the difference in the input vectors (X) associated with the point from *step 1* and *step 2* (ie. `X[step 1] - X[step 2]`) and scale this value by a random value between 0 and 1
6. Add the resultant vector from *step 5* to the X vector from *step 1*

**The resultant vector is our oversampled X.**

Repeat this process for `n_samples` the number of new points to create with this process.